# Рендер массива обьектов?

Tags: vue.js

Как отрендерить первое имья, а затем количество имен (без первого )

```
 arrParticipants: [
            {img: contactIcon, name: 'Badr al-Din', price: 1000},
            {img: contactIcon, name: 'Fatima', price: 500},
            {img: contactIcon, name: 'Fatima', price: 400},
            {img: contactIcon, name: 'Fatima', price: 1200}
        ]
```

Comment: уже дизлайк поставили))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrParticipants[0].name //получите имя первого элемента массива

arrParticipants.length - 1 //получите длину массива -1 элемент
```